# Windows 8 Action Centre Keeps Reminding Me To Turn Virus Protection On

Tags: windows-8, windows-defender

I have not installed any anti-virus software on my Windows 8 as I think that Windows Defender is enough to keep my system protected from any virus attack.  However, sometimes my Action Center shows to turn virus protection on, even though I have enabled Windows Defender.

Why is my Action Center occasionally showing this message?

Comment: A screenshot would be nice. Also have you updated the Windows Defender or not?

Comment: @HackToHell its not a dupe just read the post carefully, he is struggling with his Windows action center :)

Comment: @avirk whoopps sorry

Comment: Defender is not an AV, it protects against malware! And your assumption is plain wrong; only some decide not to use an AntiVirus (due to arrogance typically) but most of even the most experienced in IT use one (even if it's a free one)

Comment: well defender in windows 8 is combined with windows security essentials so now it is a AV.

Comment: @DaveORook - Windows Defender on Windows 8 certainly is anti-virus security suite.

Comment: @ankit689 have you check the setting menu and enabled the "Real time protection" is turn on?

Comment: Try turning off and then turning Defender on